# Force.com REST API - Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow

Tags: rest-api, oauth

Im building a multi tenant application where each client has their own subdomain. For example: `clientA.myapp.com` and `clientB.myapp.com`

I want to allow clients to integrate our app with their Salesforce installation. I have a developer account which I'm using to learn Salesforce and test everything out, and to integrate with our app I had to create a connected app, which gave me a `client_id` after it was created. In the connected app, I also had to define a `redirected_uri` which needs to be the same I use when calling the OAuth endpoint (https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize)

My question is: do `clientA` and `clientB` need to create a connected app inside their salesforce installation, and use `clientA.myapp.com/salesforce/callback` or something in their respective `redirect_uri`? In other words, can I avoid having to ask my clients for this extra step?

--

Sometimes we have the same client using two different accounts in our app. For example, `clientA-app1.myapp.com` and `clientA-app2.myapp.com` - Internally, for us they are treated as completely different accounts. But if this client only had one Salesforce installation and created one connected app, if `app1` authenticates and receives an authorisation code, and then `app2` does the same, will the authorisation code granted to `app1` be revoked? How could I avoid this scenario? Would the client need to create 2 connected apps inside their Salesforce installation?

EDIT

I've been researching how other web apps integrate with Salesforce, and particularly looked at Zapier.

They never asked me to create a connected app and provide the ID. The only asked me to click a button that redirected me to Salesforce, I logged in, and gave Zapier permission to access my stuff. So it would seem like Zapier has their own salesforce installation where they created *their* connected app, and I just gave this connected app permission to access my stuff.

How can I do something like this? All I have in salesforce is a developer account. Am I supposed to create the connected app in there, and use that to connect with our clients installations?

Comment: If someone runs into this, this other answer was exactly what I needed to understand: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70489/how-to-access-a-connected-app-from-another-org

Comment: Did you ever figure out exactly how this worked? I'm trying to do the exact same (Like Zapier style) where you don't need to make any modifications like creating a web service.